# Why is glCreateShader returning 0 on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es-2.0

Currently trying to get my C++ source code to run on iOS. It runs on Android in OpenGLES 2.0 and I've gotten everything to compile, but I am having issues in compiling the shaders. For some reason `glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)` returns 0. Here is my view controller code:

```
import Foundation
import GLKit
import OpenGLES

class SampleViewController: GLKViewController {
    @IBOutlet var glview: GLKView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        glview.context = EAGLContext(API: .OpenGLES2)

        glview.drawableColorFormat = .RGBA8888
        glview.drawableDepthFormat = .Format16
        glview.drawableMultisample = .MultisampleNone
        glview.drawableStencilFormat = .FormatNone

        preferredFramesPerSecond = 60
        let s = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Arial", withExtension: ".ttf")?.relativePath
        let cs = (s! as NSString).UTF8String
        let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>(cs)
        appInit(buffer)
    }

    override func glkView(view: GLKView, drawInRect rect: CGRect) {
        super.glkView(view, drawInRect: rect)
        glview.bindDrawable()
        appRender(Int(timeSinceLastDraw * 1000), Int32(rect.width), Int32(rect.height))
    }
}
```

Which is hooked up to a `GLKViewController` on the storyboard.

Note: `appInit(buffer)` is a call to C++ code imported through the bridging-header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I have to run my `appInit` function inside of the `drawInRect` override, since that is the first place that the `glContext` exists.

Fixed code:

```
import Foundation
import GLKit
import OpenGLES

class GanttViewController: GLKViewController {
    @IBOutlet var glview: GLKView!
    private var program = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        glview.context = EAGLContext(API: .OpenGLES2)

        glview.drawableColorFormat = .RGBA8888
        glview.drawableDepthFormat = .Format16
        glview.drawableMultisample = .MultisampleNone
        glview.drawableStencilFormat = .FormatNone

        preferredFramesPerSecond = 60
        program = 0
    }

    override func glkView(view: GLKView, drawInRect rect: CGRect) {
        super.glkView(view, drawInRect: rect)
        if(program == 0){
            let s = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Arial", withExtension: ".ttf")?.relativePath
            let cs = (s! as NSString).UTF8String
            let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>(cs)
            appInit(buffer)
            program = 1
        }

        glview.bindDrawable()
        appRender(Int(timeSinceLastDraw * 1000), Int32(rect.width), Int32(rect.height))
    }
}
```